# Session Reinitialization Issue

Tags: webrtc

RTCMultiConnection v3 (Muaz Khan)

Scenario :

1. A opens connection with B
2. B joins connection with A

Note : Above scenario is perfect

1. A opens connection with C
2. C joins connection with A

Function which generates the error:

```
    this.addRemoteSdp = function(remoteSdp, cb) {
        console.log(remoteSdp, "before")
        remoteSdp.sdp = connection.processSdp(remoteSdp.sdp);
        console.log(remoteSdp, "after")
        peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(remoteSdp), cb || function() {}, function(error) {
            if (!!connection.enableLogs) {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'), '\n', remoteSdp.type, remoteSdp.sdp);
            }
        });
    };
```

Error generated by the function:

```
RTCMultiConnection.js:2669 {} 
 answer v=0
o=- 290917982199254640 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE data
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:J7UX
a=ice-pwd:ED+zJrLHxUmKjqquaYENgvS5
a=fingerprint:sha-256 33:A9:C3:0D:F6:E6:B6:81:4A:5C:FF:C6:A0:40:93:1F:07:9A:03:9B:7E:71:8F:BC:5F:0A:F8:73:58:1A:0C:7A
a=setup:active
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
```

Comment: I didn't see any error log, what is the error message?

Comment: its mentioned in the question, the section which says "Error generated by the function:"

Comment: More Detailed error after debugging is Failed to set remote answer sdp: Calling in wrong state: STATE_INPROGRESS

Comment: is it the scenario of multi web RTC?